# Representation of a vector

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

$(l^2,\|\cdot\|_2)$ is a Hilbert space with scalar product $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}x_ky_k$.

How can I show that every vector $x\in l^2$ can be written in a form $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}x_ke^k$ where $e^k,k\in N$ are unit vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition equality 
$$
x=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x_k e^k
$$ 
means that 
$$
x=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k
$$
which by definition means that 
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\Vert x-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k\right\Vert_2=0\tag{1}
$$
Now use the fact that $\Vert z\Vert_2^2=\langle z,z\rangle$ to reduce $(1)$ to 
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty |x_k|^2=0\tag{2}
$$ 
Note that I used here the fact that $\Vert e^k\Vert_2=1$. I suggest you to recall that $x\in \ell_2$, to understand why $(2)$ holds.

Comment: Could you help me a bit more? I understood that I have to prove that $x=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k$. And I understand that it is equivalent to $(1)$ by definition. But I don't understand what do I have to do now. If you meant that I have to take second power of $(1)$, I've got this and I don't know if it is what I had to do. If it is, I don't know what I have to do after this what I got

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|x-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k\|^2_2=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle x-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k,x-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k\rangle=  
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}[\langle x,x\rangle-2\langle x,\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k\rangle+\langle \sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k,\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k\rangle]=\|x\|_2^2-2\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle x,\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k\rangle+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k\|_2^2=\|x\|_2^2-2\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle x,\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k\rangle+\|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k e^k\|_2^2$

Comment: @gov 
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\Vert x-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k e^k\right\Vert_2=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\Vert(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\ldots)-(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,0,0,\ldots)\right\Vert_2
$$
$$
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Vert(0,0,\ldots,0,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\ldots)\Vert_2
$$
$$
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty|x_k|^2\right)^{1/2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $x$ and define $x_k:=\langle x,e_k\rangle$. Now we need to prove that the vector

$$y=\sum_k x_ke_k$$
exists and equal to $x$.

First, we show that it exists: the series converges by [pythagorean identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Pythagorean_identity) ); moreover, it converges to the norm of $x$, because of [Parseval's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval_identity).

$$\|y\|^2=\left\|\sum_k x_ke_k\right\|=\sum_k x_k^2 = \|x\|^2.$$

Now clearly the difference $y-x$ is orthogonal to the $E$ - the basis of $H$, hence $y-x\in Cl(E)=H$ (because our space is complete), thus $y-x=0$.